# Woocommerce Filter Hooks

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I'm hoping to get a little insite for using filters in Woocommerce. My main question is, what am I looking for in the template files? or what are the variables that can be targeted using filters? If we look at the filters list I see filter name and files. Using this filter

single_product_small_thumbnail_size

Files - product-thumbnail.php and woocommerce-template.php

What am I looking for in those files that can be targeted and changed? Would you give me a simple example? Maybe something like change thumbnail size?

```
add_filter('filter_name', 'your_function_name');

function your_function_name( $variable ) {
// Your code
return $variable;
}
```

I understand what each part of the function and filter are, but I'm not sure what code to write for "Your code." What variable am I grabbing from the file? How do I apply the change? I can't completely wrap my mind around this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
~MK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in e.g. `woocommerce-template.php` you can filter the `shop_catalog` string:

```
$small_thumbnail_size  = apply_filters( 'single_product_small_thumbnail_size', 'shop_catalog' );
```

That string is used in the subsequent code to determine the image size to be used:

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, $small_thumbnail_size  );
```

So, if you would like to use another image size, you can filter the string like e.g.:

```
add_filter( 'single_product_small_thumbnail_size', 'my_single_product_small_thumbnail_size', 25, 1 );
function my_single_product_small_thumbnail_size( $size ) {
    $size = 'large';
    return $size;
}
```

Comment: Great! I see shop_catalog in the woocommerce-template.php. Is that a function that can be found elsewhere in the plugin? Also, the variable $size, are the available variables listed somewhere in the code? How do I know what can be filtered?

Comment: In this case, `shop_catalog` is a string, it is the filterable value. `$size` is just a name, it references the value to be filtered, you could use e.g. `$thumb`, `$string`, ... Please review: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters

Comment: and some more good info: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97356/trouble-understanding-apply-filters